# AWK command to print the pattern as below from pattern provided

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

**I have a pattern as below:**

**Pattern in a unix file:**
`{1.11.111.111 - 2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00 111111 1 302 "GET /abcd/z1/bcdfgggg?values" uri="/abcd/v2/nano" 111 111 0 "-" "abcd/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; Redmi Note 6 Pro MIUI/V10.2.2.0.bcdwvc)" "1111:1111:111:1111:11:d11e:c11c:111a" cu=0.011 nano=0.011 var="-12345" "1111:1111:111:1111:11:d11e:c11c:111a, 11.111.111.111"}`

I am trying to print the below result but the result is not printed as expected.

**Code:**
`Cat test.txt | awk -F'"' '{ print $1,$9}' |awk -F' ' '{ print $3,$6,$24}'`

**Actual Result**: `2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00 302`

**Expected Result**: `2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00 302 cu=0.011`

Comment: Could you please correctly wrap your samples in CODE TAGS by using button `{}` in your question as it is not clear.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Note this is also potentially a UUOC use: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/119

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed and a regex with three backreferences:

```
sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9:+]{14}) [0-9]+ [0-9]+ ([0-9]{3}) .*(cu=[0-9.]+).*/\1 \2 \3/' file
```

Output:

```
2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00 302 cu=0.011
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the log entry will *always* look like presented by the OP:

```
pattern='{1.11.111.111 - 2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00 111111 1 302 "GET /abcd/z1/bcdfgggg?values" uri="/abcd/v2/nano" 111 111 0 "-" "abcd/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; Redmi Note 6 Pro MIUI/V10.2.2.0.bcdwvc)" "1111:1111:111:1111:11:d11e:c11c:111a" cu=0.011 nano=0.011 var="-12345" "1111:1111:111:1111:11:d11e:c11c:111a, 11.111.111.111"}'

awk -F ' ' '{print $3,$6,$25}' <<< "$pattern"
```

Output: `2017-10-06T00:00:00+00:00 302 cu=0.011`